# Geoserver using http proxy not working

Tags: proxy, centos7

I have a Geoserver which is supposed to access external stores via an HTTP proxy ive set up, I have added my proxy details on the environmental variables (env) but the Geoserver still tries to access the store directly without the proxy.

Does anyone know how to make Geoserver access external sources via the http_proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> I have added my proxy details on the environmental variables (env)

Are you *sure*? I've had this happen using different software, when i declared the environment variables on my normal user, but ran commands as sudo - the env variables don't carry over to the "sudo session" by default, but by using the -E flag.

Also it might be that you have to declare the https_proxy variable aswell. And are you sure your variable is declared properly - ie:

```
export http_proxy="my.proxy-address.xyz:8083"
```

Comment: I have done exactly like you mentioned, i exported the environmental variable while logged in as root user.   The settings seem to be working when i try access a website from a browser (website accessed via the proxy) but the java environment (Geoserver application) seem not to use the proxy environmental variables. It keeps accessing external site directly instead of going through the proxy defined on the env

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wfs.html) you need to set the `http_proxy` variables either using a system environment variable for the executing user (!), or directly through the JVM property set (found in `catalina.sh`). There are detailed steps on how to do this on the WFS Store page. And try to disable http connection pooling.

Comment: Thats what i did, i edited the startup.sh  file in my case and added the following line         java -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://myproxyurl -Dhttp.proxyPort=80                                            Then disabled the http conncetion pooling, but it still doesnt work